# Angular and WordPress Integration

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I;m doing a simple integration of angular inside wordpress, I enqueue the angular script:

```
function angular()
{ 
wp_enqueue_script('angular', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/angular.min.js', array(), null, false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'angular');
```

And I paste this code in the page.php of the theme (Twenty Seventeen theme which is the one I'm using to test) the following code just to test :

```
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
<h1>Hello, {{ name }}!</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
</div>
```

Angular Initialize

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController]);
function MyController($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';
}
</script>
```

Ant it returns

Hello, `{{name}}`

The angular doesn't start

Comment: What does the Angular initialization JS code look like? You don't seem to be initializing it anywhere. Just loading the Angular dependency doesn't do anything.

Comment: I updated the questions.. thanks

Comment: ng-app missing?

Comment: Do you have your `ng-app` directive declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can try the following steps to figure out your Problem:

1. Check via webinspect Tools (F12) if angular is loaded.
2. Verify the angular autoload directive is set (ng-app="myApp" on body, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)
3. Look for Errors in webinspector JavaScript console

Comment: Wow I need coffee I forgot about the ng-app. Thanks